# Ubuntu 14.04 & AMD 14.6 Driver issue R7 260X

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, graphics, gpu

Okay I have searched and for some reason I am just having problems installing the Beta driver 14.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.

This is my second installation today as I messed up my last one following other posts I found in the forums/search.

I download the AMD driver and when I do everything to run it this pops up:

> Please install the required pre-requisites for package generation
>   before proceeding with AMD Catalyst installation. Please check file
>   `usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log` for more details.

I tried doing the install anyhow but had no success. The default driver for 14.04 on my 260x is terrible with low FPS in games, around 5 FPS on low vs my Windows 7 running 60 (locked max at 60 fps).

http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Latest-LINUX-Beta-Driver.aspx 
Is the link for the driver and requirements/needed packages. I tried installing the "required" packages and most of them came up as not found when doing the `apt-get install` command in the terminal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have seen many tutorials for this but it is after they have the necessary things installed for the driver. I believe it is an issue with the required packages or something in the requirements to be honest. However, if people have installed these drivers on 14.04 then someone I would imagine has ran into this problem before.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same system and card. Until today I had the same problem. Go to System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers . Select AMD proprietary drivers with updates. As of today, it installs `fglrx` with OpenGL 4.4 and everything you could want. I've got (24x improvement) in FPS using this driver.

I thought *Additional Drivers* only describes you what driver you are using. Not true, It does an automatic install of very recent proprietary driver.